# Using reflection on singleton object kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, singleton, illegalaccessexception

I have a use case where I need to use reflection to call method of my singleton class

Singleton class is as below

```
object Singleton {

fun calledFromReflection(){
    println("Successfull")
}
}
```

This is how I am using the reflection

```
val adsUtiltyCls: Class<*>? = Class.forName("com.xia.Singleton")
        val adsUtilityObj: Any? = adsUtiltyCls?.newInstance()
        if (adsUtilityObj != null) {
            val method: Method
            try {
                method = adsUtiltyCls.getDeclaredMethod("calledFromReflection")
                val value=method.invoke(adsUtilityObj)
                println("value   $value")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void com.com.xia.Singleton.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.xia.RetargetActivity>
```

Comment: If it's supposed to be a singleton why are you creating another instance?

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection? The only good reason I can think of is if the calling code doesn't know about the called singleton class at compile-time, e.g. if its name is provided as a configuration option at runtime. Though in that case, you might consider using an interface in your calling code that the called code can implement (avoiding much of the complexity and fragility of reflection); you could even use a dependency-injection framework to handle all for that for you.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you try to create an instance of your `Singleton` object which already is an instance and does not have a public constructor.

In order to access the object instance you have to change your object `adsUtilityObj` to be the object instance of the corresponding Kotlin-class:

```
val adsUtilityObj = adsUtiltyCls?.kotlin.objectInstance
```

---

Moreover, you could use [Kotlin Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html) instead of pure Java reflection. Then you can write:

```
val clazz = Class.forName("com.xia.Singleton").kotlin
clazz.functions.find { it.name == "calledFromReflection" }?.call(clazz.objectInstance)
```

or equivalently

```
Singleton::class.functions.find { it.name == "calledFromReflection" }?.call(Singleton)
```

Comment: In the last example, if the compiler knows about the `Singleton` object, won't it also know about its methods, making reflection unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be the case. But I do not know what the purpose of the reflection is here at all, so I just added it as additional information.